# Как сделать событие на tab за рамки компонента?

Tags: vue.js

У меня вопрос такой, что допустим когда с инпута перешел через нажатием tab, то все нормально срабатывает, но если повторно нажать на tab то нужно чтобы событие срабатывала на закрытие select. Как примерно это сделать?https://codesandbox.io/s/3v1zp6x1w1
Вот код, но установить в document событие tab но это срабатывает

```
methods: {
            closeOptionTab(e) {
                if (this.$refs['selected'].contains(e.target)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (this.disabled) {
                    this.disabled = false;
                }
            }
        },
created() {
            document.addEventListener("tab", this.closeOptionTab)
        }
```

А в template

Как тут быть?

Comment: Может использовать событие [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/blur)? (`v-on:blur="..."`)